# Observable.fromCallable() implementation with exception

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I am trying to do a execute a function which throws exceptions.

```
Observable.fromCallable { foo() }
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .take(1)
          .onErrorReturn { /* onError operation */ }
          .subscribe { }
```

and I want to do some other operation if it succeeds without any errors. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do some other operation if it succeeds without any errors

All of those operators would be applied to your stream unless an exception has happened, meaning that you do not have to care about *"if it succeeds"* case, you should only take care of *"if it does **not** succeed"* case.

If, for some reason, an error has occurred, only then `onErrorReturn()` would be applied.

Comment: ok so I just do this `Observable.fromCallable { foo() }
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .take(1)
          .subscribe ({// success },{// fails})`